# Cannot Edit The Contact Record That is Owned By Other Users

Tags: sharing, edit

Can I edit the `Contact` record that is owned by others related to the `Account`, without giving `Modify All` object level permission for a profile?

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a sharing rule to open up the access rights. It can be criteria or ownership based as per your use case.

Provided that, the user's profile/permission set must have Edit access to Contact object.

Refer [Define Sharing Rules](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/data_security/data_security_sharing_rules)

Here is a way to open up visibility & access rights

[image: Sharing architecture]

Comment: There's more ways than just sharing rules that you can do this, though, but you're on the right track.

Comment: just updated with a diagram